# Buttons are not working

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" RecordSetVar="obj" >
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Employee Details">
    <apex:pageBlockTable var="er" value="{!obj}" rows="5">
                    <apex:column headerValue="EID">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!er.name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ENAME">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!er.Emp_Name__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="SALARY">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!er.Salary__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="DEPTNO">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!er.Dept_no__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="JOB">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!er.Job__c}"/>
                   </apex:column>
                    
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
     
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton value="Next page" action="{!next}" />
     <apex:commandButton value="Previous page" action="{!previous}" />
     <apex:commandButton value="First Page" action="{!first}" />
     <apex:commandButton value="Last page" action="{!last}" />
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please add the code for all the methods associated with the buttons

Comment: This is only visual Force program related to standard list controller. Here the buttons are not working properly. Normally in Standard List Controller it should work. But in my program it is not working. Can you please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible reason (excerpts from [Visualforce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf), pages 57-58)

> When working with general lists there is no filtering by default, meaning the page will
> have access to every record in the system. As noted, the default size of the list displayed is
> 20 records. This can be increased (using the rows parameter on apex:dataTable and
> apex:pageBlockTable), but to provide the user with a sensible interface it’s important
> to add pagination controls. Pagination is easy to implement using List Controllers and the
> documentation for its Apex equivalent, the standardSetController class, provides some
> insight into how it works. The controller methods include GetNext() and GetPrevious() that
> allow jumping between pages, and the methods GetHasNext() and GetHasPrevious() that
> let you quickly determine whether there is a page available either side of the current one.

...

> It’s important to note that although we can control the number of rows displayed with
> apex:pageBlockTable and other tags, the size specified does not carry over to the effective
> page size of the controller. In other words, if you specify rows=”5” then your table will initially
> display rows 1 through 5 of the 20 in the controller’s current page. Clicking the Next link
> (assuming there are more than 20 relevant records in the system) would then refresh the table and
> show records 21 through 25 from the next page of 20.

That is - you may have more than 5 employees but fewer than 20 so when you click NEXT, it tries to find employees 21-25 but there are no such employees.

Or, you do have 21+ employees but when you click NEXT, you are expecting to see employees 6-10

The doc goes on to show how to fix this (in your case, you would set pageSize to 5)

> The documentation states that a custom controller extension is needed to change the size of
> pages displayed, however that is not the case! In order to change the number of records per
> controller page we must alter the PageSize member variable of the controller. We can extend
> page size as an option to the end user by providing them with a picklist of various values, and by
> adding an apex:commandButton with a NULL action to force the controller to update ...